# Union Query by ID or Name

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I am trying develop an seemingly easy to do report in which someone can enter an ID number or the Name and search and retrieve data.  I am able to get this to work only if I have all of the criteria, and I have tried a couple different ways. Each of the First, Last and IDs are boxes for them to fill in or leave empty. Without wasting a lot of space here is what I have essentially done, can anyone help?

Union:

```
Select 
worker_id as "ID",
worker_last_name as "Last",
worker_first_name as "First",
worker_phone_home as "Home_Phone",
worker_email as "Email"
from worker
where worker_id = :parm_EB_pnum --inputvalue
UNION
Select 
worker_id as "ID",
worker_last_name as "Last",
worker_first_name as "First",
worker_phone_home as "Home_Phone",
worker_email as "Email"
from worker
where (
upper(worker_first_name) like upper(:parm_EB_first) and 
upper(worker_last_name) like upper(:parm_EB_last)
)
```

This I also tried using = instead of like for similar results, I need both inputs. I attempted a CASE statement in the where clause without a UNION but I got the same results

Comment: I'm not sure that I see a question here.  Does the query return what you want?  If not, post a reproducible test case.  Post the DDL to create the `worker` table, the DML to insert a few sample rows, tell us what the bind variables are and tell us what rows you want to be returned.

Comment: it only returns rows if I fill in both the ID, first_name, and Last_name. I want it to return values when only a ID or a First & Last name is input, not all of them. Sorry I was not clear

Comment: are some of these values null?  that could cause issues.

Comment: No, each person has an ID# assigned and each person has a name, The input values could be blank yes, they may say not remember their ID but know their name obviously

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  If `:param_EB_pnum` is entered, and it matches a `worker_id`, you'll get that row no matter what `:param_EB_first` and `:param_EB_last` are.  A reproducible test case (a fiddle on sqlfiddle.com would be great) would probably help illustrate what you're seeing and what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `%` when you use `like`. Also, a `where` condition with `or` would suffice for what you are trying to do. You can also do a `trim` to remove any spaces in the input values.

```
select 
worker_id as "ID",
worker_last_name as "Last",
worker_first_name as "First",
worker_phone_home as "Home_Phone",
worker_email as "Email"
from worker
where worker_id = :parm_EB_pnum
or upper(worker_first_name) like '%'||upper(:parm_EB_first)||'%' 
or upper(worker_last_name)  like '%'||upper(:parm_EB_last)||'%'
```

Comment: Is there a way for this to work without all of the values needed? I am wondering if its my software (argos). It seems to only give me results when I have the ID, First and Last name. Its fine that it does that, but most likely people will just use one or the other, ID or Name

Comment: or in the query does that.returns a row when either of the 3 conditions is met

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Select 
worker_id as "ID",
worker_last_name as "Last",
worker_first_name as "First",
worker_phone_home as "Home_Phone",
worker_email as "Email"
from worker
where worker_id = (CASE WHEN :parm_EB_pnum > 0 THEN :parm_EB_pnum END) 
UNION
Select 
worker_id as "ID",
worker_last_name as "Last",
worker_first_name as "First",
worker_phone_home as "Home_Phone",
worker_email as "Email"
from worker
where 
upper(worker_first_name) like ( CASE WHEN :parm_EB_first IS NOT NULL THEN upper(:parm_EB_first) END)
and upper(worker_last_name) like ( CASE WHEN :parm_EB_last IS NOT NULL THEN upper(:parm_EB_last) END)
```